# how cans solve connection error in python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

def crawler(maxpage,query,s_date,e_date):

```
s_from = s_date.replace(".","")
e_to = e_date.replace(".","")
page = 1
maxpage_t =(int(maxpage)-1)*10+1
f = open("C:/Projects/Capstone/emotion_like.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')

while page < maxpage_t:
    print(page)
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}
    url = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=news&query=" + query + "&sort=0&ds=" + s_date + "&de=" + e_date + "&nso=so%3Ar%2Cp%3Afrom" + s_from + "to" + e_to + "%2Ca%3A&start=" + str(
        page)
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(url)
    cont = req.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(cont, 'html.parser')
    for urls in soup.select("._sp_each_url"):
        try:
            if urls["href"].startswith("https://news.naver.com"):
                news_detail = getnews(urls["href"])
                f.write("{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(result_list[0], result_list[1], result_list[2]))  # new style
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
    page += 10

f.close()
```

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

I try to make web crawler. When page is over 50, this error will occur.

I think the website block our connection. is it right?

And how can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is blocked over a certain number of tries, the most likely case is indeed that the connection is reset. This is usually done to prevent flooding the website and/or prevent DDOS attacks.

What you could do is make smaller iterations and then pause (for example up to 40, then sleep for 3 seconds). This way you will not spam the website.